# Include menu content from external ASP page, keeping menu item selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have the following content in multiple/every page within a new web site.

I have removed the redundant code from all the pages and added an **include** (as noted below) to all of the pages that need menu select option. Using:

```
<!--#include file ="Include.asp"-->
```

The question is how would we keep the page selected menu item highlighted for all or any selection, suppose session variable or jQuery variable pass from page to page to page?

**class="current"** somehow needs to be prefix for current page? The current code keeps the home page highlighted, if we remove class="current" we obviously lose all affects of highlighting.

Thank you, novice coder!

```
<nav>
<div id="menu-icon">Menu<span></span></div>
<ul class="menu responsive-menu">
    <li class="current"><a href="index.asp">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index1.asp">Page 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1.5</a></li>
            <li class="last-item"><a href="#">Page 1.6</a></li>
        </ul>
        <span class="menu-bottom"></span>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index2.asp">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="index3.asp">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="index4.asp">Page 4</a></li>
    <li class="last-item"><a href="index5.asp">Page 5</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to do it server side.

Using ASP code behind, you can take the request.url variable and extract the file name and then do a replace on your html like this:

```
html = html.replace("<li><a href=""file_name.asp""", "<li class=""current""><a href=""file_name.asp""")
```

If you have any other loop where you create the nav element, you can of course do the injection there.

Comment: Are you able to remote login and do a bit of on the fly coding for a few bucks through PayPal? Working on other projects and could use a little hired help?

Comment: @user3359954 .. of course I am able, check my profile page for contact info